# Android rectangle with a coloured strip on one side

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a list background like this:

[image: list background]

This is the code that achieves a rectangle with a stroke and two rounded corners.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#dddddd" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#aaaaaa" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

What I need to do now is to create the green vertical strip on the left.

My guess is I could either have a thick green stroke for the left side or place a rectangle above the the grey stroke but I haven't been able to do either of them.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You can use a LayerList and superimpose (overlay) a rectangle onto that shape.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a simple dummy view with a background of that green color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_default">

    <View
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#6BB726"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dummy"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image"
        android:id="@+id/textHolder"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Aung San"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <!-- Two other TextViews -->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try whit 9-patch, I think it will be super easy to draw exactly the same background.

[draw 9-pitch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)